# Rank for symbol table

Tags: java, symbol-table

How would I return the number of keys that is less than the given key? I just don't know where to start. I have the base start but other than that I dont know where to begin

```
public class LinkedListST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
    private Node first;      // the linked list of key-value pairs

    // a helper linked list data type
    private class Node {
        private Key key;
        private Value val;
        private Node next;

        public Node(Key key, Value val, Node next)  {
            this.key  = key;
            this.val  = val;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

public int rank (Key key) {
        if(key == null) return 0;
        //TODO
    }
```

EDIT: This is what I have so far but my for loop is wrong and is giving me errors

```
public int rank (Key key) {
    int count = 0;
    for(Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next){
        if(x.next < key){
            count++;
        }
    return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see in my answer, I have `x.key < key`, not `x.next`, because `x.next` is a `Node`, not a `Key`.

Comment: Your `{ }` are not in the right place, for one.  You are returning in the middle of each loop pass.

Comment: Perusing [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) will also help you with the correct method of comparing `Comparable` objects.   Hint: it isn't `<`.

Comment: Oh thank you, I didn't realize I had put my counter there. and would it be if (current.key.compareTo(key) > 0) count++; ?

Comment: By `current`, I assume you mean `x`?  Then no, I think you've got your comparison backwards.  But can `current.key` be null?  You originally tested if the key being passed in was `null`.  So writing `key.compareTo(x.key) > 0` might be a better test.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is now working fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
initialize counter to zero
loop over all nodes, starting at first:
   if node's key < key:
       increment count
return count
```

That should get you started.

---

**EDIT**

Ok, so you've actually posted a real attempt at writing the code, which is the secret to getting real help on Stack Overflow.

Your code, with proper indentation, ...

```
public int rank (Key key) {
    int count = 0;
    for(Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next){
        if (x.next < key){
            count++;
        }
        return count;  // <-- Note!
    }
}
```

... shows a return statement inside the loop.  Not exactly what you wanted.

The `if (x.next < key)` is also giving you grief, because you need to compare `Key` with `Key`, not `Node` with `Key`.

Finally, the `Comparable` interface requires the the `Key` to implement the `compareTo(Key other)` method.  Used like:

```
key.compareTo(x.key)
```

This returns a `-1`, `0`, or `1` depending on which is larger or if they are the same.  So you really want:

```
if (key.compareTo(x.key) < 0) {
```

or

```
if (key.compareTo(x.key) > 0) {
```

Exercise left to student.

Comment: I have added my code but my for loop is wrong and is giving me errors

Comment: by the way this is an unordered symbol table

Comment: Neither my nor @engineer's pseudo code assumed the list was sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost there, but you have three issues:

- The `return` statement is inside the `for` loop. If you corrected the indentation, you'd see that. Move it outside.
- You don't want to compare `x.next` to `key`. You want to compare `x.key` to the `key` parameter.
- You cannot compare using the `<` operator. Since `Key` is `Comparable`, you *can* compare by calling `compareTo()`.

Here is the updated code:

```
public int rank (Key key) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
        if (x.key.compareTo(key) < 0){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I had fixed the return statement, I didn't realize i had put it there. And thank you, do you know an easier way to approach these types of data structures? Ive been having a hard time with nodes and linked lists

Comment: @yenyen Nope, that's it.

Comment: @yenyen , don't reinvent the wheel (you already have some data structures in Java). Otherwise, this is the way.